# WSS 3.0 Backup/Restore Root Site Collection to Sub-Site of New Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint, backup, wss, restore

Our intranet was originally setup to be at the root of its site collection. We are trying to change this so that our new internet site will live in the root and the intranet will be a sub-site.

At this point I have created a new web application and site collection to house the internet and intranet. I used the 'stsadm -o backup' command to create a backup of our current intranet. I then ran the 'stsadm -o restore' command to restore the intranet site collection to http://wss/sites/intranet. This seems to have worked as I am able to access the intranet from this location.

The issue I now seem to have is that images, sub-sites, etc. are all making reference as if the intranet is still the root site. So for example a link to a sub-site is pointing to wss/department/technology/default.aspx and it needs to point to wss/sites/intranet/department/technology/default.aspx.

I am looking for help and/or clarification on two things:

1. Am I approaching the migration of a root site collection to a sub-site the best way?
2. How would I go about updating the link references so that they are based on the intranet now being a sub-site instead of the root site?

Comment: I submitted this to serverfault. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.